# Saving option value from Django to mongodb

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I'm new to Django. And recently am working on a website that need to show data from mongoDB and collect people's answers by offering forms. 
And now I got stuck with saving data from form to mongoDB.

I want people to only choose one answer in the dropdown form.
Here is the html:

```
                      <table>
                                <form action="/reply/" method="POST" >
                                    <td>
                                        <select name = "reply">
                                            <option value="#">Choose</option>
                                            <option value="support">Support</option>
                                            <option value="against">Against</option>
                                            <option value="related">Related</option>
                                            <option value="irrelated">Irrelated</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <input type="submit" value="OK!">
                                </form>
                      </table>
```

And here is my view

```
def labeling(request):
form = request.POST
if form.is_valid():
    db.label.insert({
        reply : form,
        Post_ID : reequest.GET['id']
            })
    db.label.update
    return HttpResponseRedirect("")
```

I have created collection named "label".

I have been working on this problems for a long time...I'll appreciate if someone could help me...

Comment: It turned out that, I didn't match the right action to view function...In the html, I use "/reply/", but in the view, I use "labeling". So just change "/reply/" into "labeling", it would work!

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you :-

Your views.py :-

```
def labeling(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormClassName(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.reply = form.cleaned_data['reply']
            instance.postId = form.cleaned_data['postId']
            instance.save() 
            data = {'success':True,'msg':'Store user data successfully'}
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data),content_type="application/json")

    else:
        data = {'success':False,'msg':'Not Store user data successfully'}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data),content_type="application/json")
```

Your forms.py :-

```
class FormClassName(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = modelName
        fields = [
                  "reply", 
                  "postId",
                  ]
```